# customize slides-control

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a little thinking problem in PowerPoint.

We have a macro that creates and fills slides. Behind the macro there is a database with many text modules that should make the work faster and easier.

The slides are often edited several times in the live presentation because the content is constantly changing.

When the presentation is started, the presenter view (kiosk-mode) is active. If a slide is now processed with the macro, it takes between 2 and 10 seconds for the changes to be updated. This is only the case if the slide to be processed is in the "visible" area of ​​the refent view. Everything that is outside the view is changed immediately.

Now I have created my own presenter view (kiosk-mode). I realized the preview as follows:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides (ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideNumber) .Export _
ActivePresentation.path & "\ preview.jpg", "JPG", SW / 2, SH / 2

Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture (ActivePresentation.path & "\ preview.jpg")
```

Now my question(s):
Can you somehow load the preview image softly into the PictureBox without saving it first?

or does anyone have any idea why changing is so extremely slow with active Refent view?

[image]

Comment: You cannot load a picture with `LoadPicture` that wasn't saved before and you cannot export a slide as image without saving it as  a picture. So the answer is: No, you can't. But anyway I see no issue with saving it to a temporary file (which you can delete after loading the picture). • Can you explain more detailed what *"why changing is so extremely slow with active Refent view"* means? Do you mean `LoadPicture` is too slow?

Comment: I mean it's slow once the speaker view is active. Without this view it is very fast. Please look at the screenshot.

Comment: Ok, but what is *"it"*? What exactly is the slow part? Which line of code does make it slow? The export? Or loading the picture? We need to figure out which code makes it slow otherwise it is hard to tell why it happens.

Comment: I can't understand why it's so slow.
In live mode, it is only slow when the presenter view is active and only when the slide to be edited is in the immediate vicinity. If the presenter view is disabled or the slide to be edited 5 to 6 farther away, then everything goes without loss of time.

Comment: And you won't find out if you don't tell us **which code** is the slow one. See my comment above.